# How to convert json variable to table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have created a JSON type variable that looks like so, named group.

```
'{"SG1": ["2", "4"], "SG2": ["6", "8", "10"], "SG3": ["9"]}'
```

The idea is to create multiple values for a single key for example PF1 is a group (key) that has a list of values.

I want to create a table for such JSON variable that can give me output like,

| group | values |
| --- | --- |
| PF1 | 2,4 |
| PF2 | 6,8,10 |
| PF3 | 9 |

The value column can be a string or comma-separated integer values, string is preferred.
I have tried

```
SELECT group ->> 'PF1' as group_1
from metadata;
```

Ths gives me a blank cell.

I am working with JSON in PostgreSQL for the first time so I have no idea about functions that might help me achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That input is invalid JSON to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Edited.

Comment: So what is the rule to map e.g. `SG1` to `PF1`? Is it always just replacing `SG` with `PF`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me, what you are trying to achieve, but it seems you want each key/value pair as a row in the output:

```
select t.*
from metadata m
  cross join jsonb_each_text(m."group") as t("group", values)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3e317cc5fceb0df5790695aec22d34a9)

If your `group` column isn't `jsonb` but `json` you need to use `json_each_text()`

---

Note that `group` is reserved keyword and needs to be quoted every time you use it. It would be easier if you found a different name.

Comment: That's what I want but not exactly, I can do the rest of the part on my own. Just one question. What is the data type for the values column? Is it a string? Can I do something like 2,3,4 instead of ["2", "3", "4"]